# Calculating the time difference between two GMT time instances as String

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to get time difference between dates as String format like 4 hours ago.

Here is my code

To my understanding   `Calendar.getInstance()` gives time as GMT. my server time is GMT so the difference should be GMT Vs GMT however the difference with this code is GMT (Server) Vs. GMT +5 ( My Current timezone)

How can i make the difference GMT only?

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date convertedDate = new Date();

        Calendar systemCal = Calendar.getInstance();            
        long currentTime = systemCal.getTimeInMillis();

        /***********************************/
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        try {
            convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
        cal.setTime(convertedDate);
        /***********************************/
        CharSequence myDateString = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(cal.getTimeInMillis(), currentTime, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
        return myDateString.toString();
```

Comment: You can pass lacale into constructor of SimpleDateFormat

Comment: SimpleFormat has nothing to do with it. its already in GMT

Comment: Calendar.getInstance() does not give time in GMT. It returns the time zone of your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following codes. It demonstrates clearly on how to parse a String datetime to GMT timezone. Key point is the first line which sets the default timezone.

```
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        Date convertedDate = dateFormatGmt.parse("2015-01-29 10:05:00");
        long diffSeconds = (cal.getTimeInMillis() - convertedDate.getTime()) / 1000;
        System.out.println("convertedDate: " + convertedDate);
        System.out.println("current: " + cal.getTime());
        System.out.println("Difference in seconds: " + diffSeconds);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i found the simple solution. i turned my server time to my timezone and then calculated the difference . Simplest solution so far. Setting dateFormatGmt.setZone(TimeZone.getDefault())

Answer (score 0):

The Calendar.getInstance() return the time zone the computer is set to. So unless you always have control over that i would advice using the getInstance(TimeZone zone) method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28java.util.TimeZone%29

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

But if you want a easier way to do it i would advice to look in to joda time.

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: its still the same, i think by default it does send GMT time, its the porblem with DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString